# Linearization of a fixed point (dynamical systems)

Tags: dynamical-systems, self-learning, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

Just looking at the following piece of math from Strogaz's dynamic / chaos book.

[image: View image here...]

What I don't understand is the last part, where he claims that O($Ƞ^{2}$) is negligible if $f^{'}(x^{*})!=0$.
I guess I'm also not so sure about why the taylor expansion $f(x^{*}+Ƞ)$ = $f(x^{*}) + Ƞf^{'}(x^{*}) + O(Ƞ^{2}) $

It does make sense to think of it as : $f(x+Ƞ)$ is equal to $f(x^{*})$  + some change induced by Ƞ and some error term. Where the change is approximated by $Ƞ * df/dx$. But how come the second term of the expansion isn't equal to $(x-(x^{*}+Ƞ)) f^{'}(x^{*}+Ƞ)$ where $x^{*}+Ƞ = x$ so the whole thing should just be $0$?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Best regards,
Chen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Taylor expansion is just the general formula $f(x + h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + \frac{h^2}{2!}f''(x) + ...$

This is not a rigorous proof of the claim, but "intuitively" you can discount higher order $\eta$ terms as $\eta$ is a small perturbation - the square of it (and cube, etc) can be taken to be negligibly small. Then $\dot{\eta} = f'(x^*) \eta$ can be used to see how perturbations grow with time (what is the solution to this ODE)?

This issue is when $f'(x^*) = 0$ - here stability cannot be determined without examining higher order terms which are themselves non-linear. For example, consider $f(x) = x^3 + c$. Linear stability anslysis can be used if $c = 1$, but not $c =0 $ (why?)

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve the ODE here actually. I'm trying to do the following: dη /dx˙= f′(x∗)η => dη /n ˙=f′(x∗) dx => ln(η) +c1˙= f(x∗) + c2 => η˙= e ^ (f(x∗) + c2) - c1 Not sure what to do next and if doing what I did earlier is correct. But regardless this shows that the perturbation η˙either grows exponentially into infinity or diminishes down to near 0 depending on the sign of f'(x*)?

Comment: And for the second (why?), I'm not quite sure. Indeed it is evident that when c= 0 the only stationary point is x*= 0 so f'(x*)=0 and  x*=1 for c= 1 means f'(x*) =1. Certainly we can use linear stability analysis in the second case. But I'm not sure how to make of this intuitively which offers insight into the linear stability analysis technique. It seems to me to be akin to "second derivative test for maxima/minima/saddle point" and can be derived intuitively by considering f'(x) the second derivative of x(t)...

Comment: Your solution is correct - $f'(x^*)$ is simply a constant for our purposes here, so you integrate as you did - however you only need one constant of integration when solving definite integrals (move to one side and write $c = c_2 - c_1$). Your statement about growth or decay is correct, and is exactly why we can look at the sign of the equilibrium point: growth means stable, decay means unstable (this is the key point!). This also links to your second point.